# Implementing "Bulletproofs: Short Proofs for Confidential Transactions and More" in C++

Tags: c++, cryptography

I'm going through [Bulletproofs](https://crypto.stanford.edu/bulletproofs/). So far I've implemented some utility functions for vector inner product, vector power, and some of the equations given in the paper. I plan to implement the protocol given in the paper as a standalone code, and later try to integrate it with the secp256k1lib library.

I cannot understand how generators g and h are to be chosen. I'm coding in C++ and could not find libraries to get generators and groups. Or maybe writing my own functions for them. Also I understand that bulletproofs have already been included here in this [repo](https://github.com/apoelstra/secp256k1-mw/tree/bulletproofs). However I could not pinpoint to where the code is situated.

Any help in understanding the code in the repo, or help me with my own implementation would be appreciated.

Update:
I found [Function description in the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoHnn.png). Any ideas where such a function can be found (libraries, etc.)?